# Want to delete woocommerce coupon in bulk from phpmyadmin based on published date

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I want to delete all these woocommerce coupons that's publish date is older than 30 days from current date. I have almost 15K auto generated coupons that needs to be cleared up. From here I got an sql query like below which delete all coupon

```
DELETE a, b
FROM hge_posts AS a
JOIN hge_postmeta AS b
WHERE b.post_id = a.ID
AND a.post_type = 'shop_coupon'
AND b.meta_key = 'discount_type'
```

I want it to be able to select based on publish date. Any help is appreciated.